# Rounded Borders not working CSS style sheet for HTML website

Tags: html, css

What should be displayed: A border with rounded corners done with the aside element. What is displayed: A square box border with the correct outline color; however they are not rounded.

When I add a background color: a box with rounded corners appears inside the regular square box outline of the aside element.

Here is my code that is associated with what I am trying to do.

```
      <section id="main">

         <aside>
            <p>The Grand Junction Neonatal Intensive Care Unit offers comprehensive neonatal 
               diagnostic and treatment facilities for critically ill newborns. We're dedicated 
               to providing the highest quality care for all newborns, ranging from healthy 
               neonates to sick or premature newborns requiring close observation or intensive care.
            </p>
            <p>All of the neonatologists are board certified. We believe it's critical that our 
               clinicians learn about the latest advances in neonatal intensive care to
               better serve the community of Grand Junction.
            </p>
         </aside>
      </section>

and now the styles:

/* Aside Styles */

aside {
    color: rgb(149, 91, 42);
    float: right;
    margin: 30px;      
    outline: 3px solid rgb(149, 91, 42);
    width: 50%;

    /* Rounded corners here. Not Working. Don't know why. Please give feedback. */
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

aside p {
    font-size: 90%;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/Lfhhutp5/

Answer (score 4):

Use `border` instead of `outline`.  You were close!

See: http://jsfiddle.net/wyxjtacg/

Comment: You'll need to correct your link... remove a slash at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add border: 1px solid black; instead of  'outline'.